# Definition of Analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The Analytic functions are defined as $f$ is analytic on the domain $D$ if for any $x_0$ in $D$, one can write $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(x-x_0)^n$$ and the series is convergent to $f(x)$ for $x$ in the neighbourhood of $x_0$.

Equivalently, it's Taylor Series:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^n(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$$ converges to $f(x)$ for $x$ in the neighbourhood of $x_0$ (in the mean square sense).

This is more of copy from [**Wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function).

I have a few trivial questions

Q. First is it different from saying, a function is analytic if it can be well approximated with Taylor Series (I mean is not for some $x$ in the neighborhood of $x_0$ redundant)?

Q. Second, what does the note in bracket "(in the mean square sense)" mean? Is mean square sense=reference to euclidean metric?

Q. From this definition how can I conclude that $e^{(-1/z)},z\in \mathbb{C}$ is not analytic?

**Edit** Let's define $z \neq 0$ . Then is it analytic or not?

Comment: Regarding your third question: The limit of $e^{-1/z}$ is not well-defined for $z \to 0$. For example, what happens if $z$ approaches zero along the *negative real axis*?

Comment: Let's define $z \neq 0$ . Then is it analytic or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $z \neq 0$ then the function is [holomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function). There are several ways to prove this. The obvious one is to consider the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations):

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
U(x,y) &=& e^{-x/(x^2+y^2)}\cos\left(\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\right) , \\
V(x,y) &=& e^{-y/(x^2+y^2)}\sin\left(\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right) . \\
\end{array}$$

A straight-forward application of the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule), [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) and [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) shows that $U_x = V_y$ and $U_y = -V_x$. Thus $f(x,y) = U(x,y) + iV(x,y)$ is holomorphic for all $z \in \mathbb{C}^{\times}$.

Comment: You got $x$ and $y$ mixed up a bit. $e^{-x\cdots}\cos(y\cdots),e^{-x\cdots}\sin(y\cdots)$

Answer (score 3):

As far as the third question is concerned: consider the closely related function defined on $\mathbf{R}$ by $f(x) = 0$ for $x\leqslant 0$ and $f(x) = \exp(-1/x)$ otherwise is not analytic in $x=0$. For clearly in every neighbourhood of $0$ there exists points in $\mathbf{R}$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$, however it can be shown by induction that $(D^n f)(0) = 0$ so that the Taylor series expansion around 0 vanishes and therefore cannot represent $f$.